# Barrow's Geometric Proof of Power Rule

Tags: calculus, geometry, math-history

I have been working through Barrow's Geometrical Lectures, but am having an extremely hard time following his proofs of Theorems IX.1-IX.3, which amount to a geometric (and I think limit-free) demonstration of the power rule for positive rationals.  Can anyone offer an explanation of his proof?

Comment: For those (like myself) unfamiliar with the work, I believe [this may be a link to the book in question](https://archive.org/details/geometricallectu00barruoft).

Comment: Yes!  Thank you for adding that.  The relevant section begins on page 101 as numbered in the book.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Answer (score 0):

Barrow is notoriously difficult to follow but he has been studied by scholars like Antoni Malet; see e.g., [this publication](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1600-0498.1997.tb00025.x/abstract).